# Kruskal-Wallis test for ranking data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

I have a complex experimental design where there are 3 groups, and in each group, a ranking/comparison is made between items (list of items). Each ranking is associated with 9 measurements on a 5 point Likert scale.

The data summary for a pre-test is (Group1: 40 comparisons coming from 7 people, Group2: 20 comparisons coming from 3 people, Group3: 8 comparisons coming from 6 people).

Now, I have to analyse whether these 3 groups on 9 measurements are the same or different. I think of applying the Kruskal-Wallis test, but it considers n1=40, n2=20 (items in group G1, G2). Still, I wonder (7,3) people should be involved in this as n1 and n2 deal with only comparisons , or it does not matter as the effect between groups and measurements are the only consideration here.

In G1 and G2, each person does a minimum of 5 comparisons to a maximum of 10 comparisons, and in G3, a minimum of 1 comparison to a maximum of 2 comparisons.

The 9 measurement/questions are the same across groups for every comparison. For example, the table looks like this.

| group | measurement | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | M1 | 2 |
| g2 | M9 | 4 |
| g3 | M1 | 5 |
| g2 | M2 | 4 |
| g2 | M6 | 3 |
| g3 | M9 | 4 |

How do I do about this experiment with the Kruskal-Wallis test? Should I consider any other statistical test?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Let me rephrase and ask few questions: 1) you have 3 groups with 7, 3, and 6 people respectively. Each individual ranks 9 items. So, there are rankings nested in individuals nested in groups. Right? Could you provide us a table with sample data? How do you enter such data? How rows and columns are organized?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Each individual rank one or more items and answer the 9 questions related to each ranking. 3 groups imply the way they are ranking items differs. But the 9 questions they answer related to their ranking is the same across all the groups.

Comment: So, what does “40 comparison from 7 people” mean, then? Why are there 40 from 7 people, but 8 from 6 people?

Comment: 40 comparison (for example, one comparison would be (item1, chooses over item10), once they do this comparison I have 9 questions/measurements related to this comparison. So 7 people did this 40 comparison and 9 measurements related to each of this comparison.

Comment: So individuals are nested in groups (based on comparisons?) and comparisons are nested in individuals. For each comparison, there are 9 questions, right? How do you create groups based on comparisons? I still recommend sharing a table of sample data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123339/discussion-between-rosnikv-and-t-e-g).